# Page to Page Navigation, NavigationService becomes null

Tags: wpf

I have loaded Page 1 in MainWindow using Frame and when i try to navigate from Page 1 to Page 2 below error pops up. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

When we checked in Page 1, NavigationService becomes null.

In Page 1, we tried below methods for navigation, but still we are getting above error and NavigationService was still null. Kindly Please help us to solve error.

```
 1. Uri uri = new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

    this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);



2. Page2 page2 = new Page2();

    NavigationService.Navigate(page2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NavigationService` property of the `Frame` instead of the window:

```
frame.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
```

---

```
<Frame x:Name="frame" />
```

Comment: I am new to wpf, could you explain how to access frame defined in MainWindow.xaml in Page 1

Comment: Give the frame an x:Name and then access it by this name in the code-behind. The first line in my answer is code-behind and the second is the Frame in the XAML markup.